# How to decrease the height of the text selection background using css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$('#description').mouseup(function(e) {
  textSelected = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).extractContents()
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(textSelected);
    window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(span);
})
```

```css
#description {
  line-height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut egestas leo, nec ultricies purus. Cras hendrerit ex tellus, ut mattis mauris ultrices vel. Sed iaculis leo sit amet laoreet posuere.</div>
```

I have a div with a few lines of text in it. I increased the line height, which also increased the height of the text selection background. The image below might explain it better:

[text-selection-background-height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foSAD.png)

[text-selection-gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36KfZ.gif)

I am able to change it's color from blue to the required color but couldn't decrease the height of the text selection background.

Answer (score 1):

ok,Try it

```
    <div id='description'>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> 
    <span>Fusce ut egestas leo, nec ultricies purus.</span> 
    <span>Cras hendrerit ex tellus, ut mattis mauris ultrices vel. Sed iaculis leo sit amet laoreet posuere.</span>
    </div>

#description span{
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

so you can set spaces between lines but you need wrap it inside tag if possible!
and change the spaces instead of using line-height to margins !

Answer (score 1):

With purely CSS, you cannot decouple the `line-height` and the height of the
`::selection`. Only a handful of properties allowed for selection:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection#Allowable_properties

You had the logic correct, but `:selection` should be `::selection`. If you make
that change, the default selection background will disappear completely.

```css
::selection {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #b040b0;
}
```

`::selection` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. It requires two colons
(`::`), unlike pseudo-classes which require only one ([more
from MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements)).

Since you already used JavaScript to wrap selected elements with a `<span>` and
highlight them, the only visual styles now will be your yellow highlight and
the new text shadow.

**Notes about accessibility and user experience:**

I don't know what you're building or who it's for, but I feel obliged to mention
a couple of points here.

Take care to consider the color contrast of your user interfaces. The yellow
against white will be indistinguishable to a significant portion of the
population:

https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=FFFF00&bcolor=FFFFFF

On another note, think about the people who will use your interface. If they
highlight some text, will they understand that the text-shadow represents the
browser selection vs. the yellow highlight being something else? Would they
understand that the yellow highlighted text is not what will be copied when they
press Control-c? (Etc.)

Again, this might not apply to your situation, but these things are hard to keep
in mind when you're building cool fancy stuff.